# ScrollTop or ScrollTo not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying by hours to implements the Scroll animation but it don't work! I've used a various libraries but no one work.

A snippet of JQuery script:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#menu a").click(function() {
    var menuID = $(this).attr("href");
    $("body").animate({scrollTop: $(menuID).offset().top}, "slow");
    return false;
});

</script>
```

The full code: [here](http://pastebin.com/myT6Sh7W)
Website: [here](http://churrascariasenador.com.br/projetos/chapeado)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#menu a").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var menuID = $(this).attr("href");
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(menuID).offset().top}, "slow");
    return false;
});

</script>
```

You need to change it to `html, body` instead of just `body`

Comment: If you want to, you can see the code of my site completely, I edited my post.

Comment: As mentioned bellow preventDefault() should fix it

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.preventDefault()`

```
<script>
    $("#menu a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var menuID = $(this).attr("href");
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(menuID).offset().top}, "slow");
    return false;
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get it to work try below code, use html, body instead of body

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#menu a").click(function() {
    var menuID = $(this).attr("href");
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(menuID).offset().top}, "slow");
    return false;
});

</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be html, body?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('html, body').animate({   scrollTop: $(menuID).offset().top}, "slow");
```